# Rails Activerecord: How to delete null values from join table on update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model, orders, that accepts up to 5 hotels, referenced by hotel_id through a join table, hotels_orders.

```
has_many :hotels_orders
has_many :hotels, :through => :hotels_orders
accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotels_orders, :allow_destroy => :true, :reject_if => proc {|a| a['hotel_id'].blank?}
```

This works fine when saving data from the form.

However, if the user then changes the value in a select list to remove a previously selected hotel (ie. changes the value to empty/null), then the model does not delete that combination from the join table, so when I re-open the form, the previous (non-empty) value is still there.

I'm new to Rails, grateful if somebody could point me in the right direction.